# How close application by DrawerMenu android

Tags: java, android, slidingdrawer

I have an DrawerMenu, but I cannot close my application in option available on displayView (case 5)

can you please help me in this problem??

follow my code

```
 private void displayView(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    String title = getString(R.string.app_name);
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            //fragment = new HomeFragment();
            //title = getString(R.string.title_home);
            break;
        case 1:

            break;
        case 2:

            break;

        case 3:

            break;

        case 4:

            break;

        case 5:
            SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
            editor.clear().commit();

            finish();

        default:
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling `finish()` you should use this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

And you'll send the user to the home page.